# Vim scripting and Matlab header templates

Tags: matlab, vim

what I'm trying to achieve is to create a simple function in my vimrc that should add the help commnent-block in a matlab file based on the function definition provided as first line. I once have found googling around a similar function but I'm not able to find it anymore while other solutions that have shown up use external languages such python and perl. I'd like to learn how to write my own functions while keeping vimrc clean.

The function should simply replace some placeholders I saved in a template that looks like these:

```
function [a,b] = func(c,d)
% a
%   INPUTS:
%   <+INPUTS+>
%   OUTPUTS:
%   <+OUTPUTS+>
```

The basic idea is to map ,mh to  MatlabHeader function that parse the first line, searches for possible inputs and outputs variables, save them in two separate lists and replace the correct placeholders.

I'm stucked in understanding how to add create a pre-formatted string that should replace the <++> stuff.

Here is my code:

```
function! MatlabHeader()

   let lista = split(getline("."))
   let outputList = matchstr(lista[1],'\(\w,\?\)\+')
   let outputs = split(outputList,",")
   let length = len(lista)
   let inputList = matchstr(lista[length-1],'(\(\w,\?\)\+)')
   let inputList = substitute(inputList,"(","","")
   let inputList = substitute(inputList,")","","")
   let inputs = split(inputList,",")

   :%s/<+INPUTS+>/\=inputs/g
   :%s/<+OUTPUTS+>/\=outputs/g

endfunction
```

This now "works" quite fine a part from the fact that the second input/output element in each list will be placed at the beginning of the newline and every attempt to add a tab or spaces are completely ignored.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've `split()` the original parameters into Lists, you need to `join()` them again. Else, Vim will take each element as a separate line, and plainly insert that.

```
:%s/<+INPUTS+>/\=join(inputs, "\n%   ")/g
```

---

It looks like you could benefit from using one of the snippets plugins. It's fine to try to implement a solution yourself to discover the problem space and learn, but it's unlikely you can match the functionality of a well-maintained plugin.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

Comment: Hi Ingo thanks a lot for you answer that worked indeed. I'll look into snippets as you suggested! I cannot vote up your answer, I'm too newbie ;(